# Calling JNI Native functions from other native functions

Tags: multithreading, function, java-native-interface, native

I am implementing an android app using JNI ,

I have some JNI functions ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
// other header files

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_projectpmic_NativeLib_get_1clock_1status
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint v)

{ / will do something
 pthread_t native_thread ;  
 pthread_create(&native_thread,NULL,native_thread_funtion,NULL) ;
}
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_projectpmic_NativeLib_get_name
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint v)

{ / will do something


}

void *native_thread_function(void* args)
{
    /*I want to call the above get_name()  function in this thread function ,       
  // How to do that ? */

}
```

Note : These two functions are in same .c file

Comment: No you don't. That would lead to an infinite recursion via an infinite number of threads.

Comment: Yeah I get that .. What if I want to call any other JNIfunction ..Lets say I have a JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_projectpmic_NativeLib_get_name(JNIEnv *env , jobject obj, jint v) {  }  How to call this get_name function .....Thanks

Comment: Sorry For the trouble got a method to do so

Answer (score 0):

To call a JNI method from an arbitrary native method you need a JNIEnv pointer, and the only place to get one is from AttachCurrentThread().